# DocuSign API: Sign Here Tab - Optional signature

Tags: docusignapi

I see there is an 'Optional' parameter for the Sign Here Tab. I am wondering if it is possible to make it so that if a signature is not given within x number of days, to consider the recipient complete and move on to the next recipient. Is something like this doable with Docusign API?

In other words, give the signer x number of days to sign, or else move on to next recipient so the envelope can be completed in timely fashion.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expiration date can be set at an envelope level.  DocuSign does NOT support setting per recipient expiration for an envelope.

See this [blog](https://www.docusign.com/blog/quick-tip-reminders-and-expirations/) for more information

Comment: Thanks for that info. So if I were to set the 'Optional' parameter to TRUE for recipient #3 (out of 4), and recipient #3 does not sign, is it possible to still have the envelope move past recipient #3 and allow recipient #4 to complete the envelope request?  EDIT: I guess I am not sure how setting Optional to TRUE plays out in a live scenario. What happens if they never sign?

Comment: You can set recipient #3 & #4 at the same routing order, so that both of them can sign independently of each other.  However if there is recipient #5 at a higher routing order then both #3 & #4 have to sign to get #5.  You can also consider using other [recipient types](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/recipients#types) based on your usecase

Comment: Irrespective of the Tabs placed on the document, for a document to move to the next recipient, a signer will to have to open the document in the signing ceremony and click Finish.

Comment: I am struggling to understand how the 'Optional' parameter on the signHereTabs work. Could you enlighten me? If a recipient has their signHereTab with Optional set to TRUE, how does that play out in a signing scenario? What causes the envelope to complete if the recipient chooses never to sign?

Comment: When you set 'Optional=true' on the signHere tab, the signer does not have to click on the specific tab to complete signing. Signer can just click on other required tabs and complete signing by clicking the finish button.  If there is only one SignHere tab on the document with 'Optional=true', signer will still have to open the signing session and click on Finish to complete the signing. Only then the envelope will move to the next recipient.

Comment: Ok I see. So even with 'Optional=true', the signer must at least open the document and click on Finish in order for the envelope to move on to the next recipient. Do I have that right?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.